# How to use a variable, which contains a regex, in vimrc

Tags: regex, variables, vim

Short version: I'm trying to do something like this in `.vimrc`

```
let my_regex = "some regex"
autocmd Syntax * syn match CamelCase my_regex transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained
```

but it apparently does not work - the variable `my_regex` is not expanded or recognized. If I directly replace the variable with its content - it works perfectly. What I'm missing here?

---

Story: after googling a bit, I found a trick [here](https://github.com/teranex/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc), which makes vim's spell-check to ignore camel case words (upper and lower). But I expanded the regex to ignore several other words and the expression became very ugly. So, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
" ignore camel case  "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = "\(\<\|_\)\%(\u\l*\)\{2,}\(\>\|_\)\|\<\%(\l\l*\)\%(\u\l*\)\{1,}\>"

" ignore upper-case only words  "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "\|\<[A-Z]*\>"

" ignore words, which contain '_' or a digit  "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "\|\<[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9_]\+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\>"

" something ese ..  "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "something"  

autocmd Syntax * syn match CamelCase vim_spellcheck_ignore_words transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained
```

---

### Final solution:

```
" begin regex "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = "/" 

" ignore upper and lower camel case words "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "\\(\\<\\|_\\)\\%(\\u\\l*\\)\\{2,}\\(\\>\\|_\\)\\|\\<\\%(\\l\\l*\\)\\%(\\u\\l*\\)\\{1,}\\>"

" ignore all-caps words "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "\\|\\<[A-Z]*\\>"

" ignore words, which contain a digit or '_' "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "\\|\\<[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9_]\\+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\\>"

" end of regex "
let vim_spellcheck_ignore_words = vim_spellcheck_ignore_words . "/"

autocmd Syntax * exe "syn match CamelCase" vim_spellcheck_ignore_words "transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained"
```

Summary of the solution (based on the initial approach):

- surround the regex in `//`
- escape all slashes
- use `exe` (`execute`) to evaluate the expression

---

Alternative:

```
autocmd Syntax * syn match CamelCase
    \ "\(\<\|_\)\%(\u\l*\)\{2,}\(\>\|_\)\|\<\%(\l\l*\)\%(\u\l*\)\{1,}\>
    \ \|\<[A-Z]*\>
    \ \|\<[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9_]\+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\>"
    \ transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syn` does not expect an expression. I don't remember exactly what ex commands expect an expression appart from `:exe` `:let` and `:echo` family of commands. So if you want to use variables, you **must** use the `:exe` command to interpolate your variables:

```
autocmd Syntax * exe "syn match CamelCase" my_regex "transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained"
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains the issue. We're almost there, but it's still not working, gives plenty of errors. Adding `.` to concatenate the strings removed some of the errors, but there's one more left. Please check my comment under @Kent's answer.

Comment: The '.' is intentionally not used. BTW: What does your regex look like and do you have a delimiter before it? If not, use something like this `:let myreges="/<regex_here_without_slashes>/"`

Comment: Aha, I tried with the dots and without them - the result is the same. Please check my edit for more information and thanks one more time. About the regex with `/../` format - when I added the `/` chars to surround my regex, the errors are gone, but it does not seem to work - still counts the camel case words for errors (just like at the very beginning).

Comment: You need delimiters for the pattern. That is the correct way see `:h :syn-pattern`. The fact that the errors are gone is a good sign. However I haven't checked your regex, but are you sure, it is correct? Can you see your manual pattern if you dump your syntax rules `:syn`

Comment: BTW: without the '.' multiple arguments are simply concatenated using a space. If you don't need the space use the implicit '.' to concatenate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the `.` that's really helpful for me. About the regex - I'm positive it's OK, because when I replace the variable manually with the **same** regex, it works fine. But I've missed something - you've noted `regex_here_without_slashes` and I didn't remove any slashes, which seems to be a mistake. Which slashes must be removed? I'm looking at http://vimregex.com/ and there are always slashes there for the special chars (like `(<ul` and others).

Comment: Also, the regex is in `:syn`'s output, just without the slashes, like: `(<|_)%(ul*){2,}(>|_)|<%(ll*)%(ul*){1,}>` (this is the first part only).

Comment: Ha! Here's a difference - if I manually set the regex directly in `autocmd`, `:syn` reports the regex **with** slashes: `/\(\<\|_\)\%(\u\l*\)\{2,}\(\>\|_\)\|\<\%(\l\l*\)\%(\u\l*\)\{1,}\>/`. I'll try escaping the slash.

Comment: Well, that's something now! Thanks for showing me `:syn`. Now it works with a single var, now I must figure out a way to concatenate regexes (as it's not trivial, of course :) )

Comment: I figured it out finally! Thank you very much! I'll update my question.

Comment: My pleasure ;) You could also use a different separation character. Makes the regex easier to parse later on.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What do you mean exactly? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: instead of having to escape the `/` in the search pattern, because you are using it as a delimiter, use e.g. `#` as delimiter for the pattern.

Comment: But I'm escaping the `\`, like: `\\(`, not `/`. And they are totally different in this case. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question right.

To "build" your command/autocmd dynamically, you could use `:execute` like:

```
autocmd Syntax * exe "syn match CamelCase " . variable ." .... rest commands"
```

Comment: Thanks, we're almost there.. there's an error now: `Error detected while processing Syntax Auto commands for "*":
E475: Invalid argument: CamelCase(<|_)%(ul*){2,}(>|_)|<%(ll*)%(ul*){1,}>|<[A-Z]*>|<[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9_]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*>transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained
W18: Invalid character in group name`. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: Whoops.. stupid mistake. I added the spaces (after `CamelCase` and before `transparent`) and there are other errors  now: `Error detected while processing Syntax Auto commands for "*": E402: Garbage after pattern:  ... E475: Invalid argument: CamelCase ... E402: Garbage after pattern: `, where `...` is `(<|_)%(ul*){2,}(>|_)|<%(ll*)%(ul*){1,}>|<[A-Z]*>|<[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9_]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*> transparent containedin=.*Comment.*,.*String.*,VimwikiLink contains=@NoSpell contained`. The second error (invalid argument) is shown twice (after hitting enter). Sounds like some stupid mistake

Comment: Please see my edit for better formatting. And thanks once again for the time and help!